# NLP library for POS tagging

Tags: java, nlp, pos-tagger

I am looking for a reputable Java, Open Source (preferably) library/package that takes text as an input and identifies and marks Parts of Speech in it.

Components like:

```
Verbs + Tense + Passive/Active {Simple Present, Past Progressive, Past Passive, Present Perfect ... } 
Prepositions of movement {from, to...}
Prepositions of time and place {in, at, on...}
Adverbs of manner {fast, here, outside ... }
Comparatives {more, less ... }
Superlatives {most, least ... }
Adverbs of quantity {many, all... }
Conditionals 
Relative pronouns
Relative adverbs
Modal Verbs
```

This list is something I found online, but I am sure there is a better, standard tagging to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to have a look to this influential NLP library from Stanford University.

[POS tagging Java library](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Wall Street Tree Bank / Penn Tree Bank` (which is completely annotated by hand) as the corpus for setting up the training data for POS tagging.

It is available from LDC for a rather big fee of $1500+: [ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/catalogEntry.jsp?catalogId=LDC99T42](http://ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/catalogEntry.jsp?catalogId=LDC99T42)